# How to limit max return rows of PostGRest?

Tags: postgresql, nginx, postgrest

I'm running a Postgrest api on a database with roughly 30 million rows. Sometimes I accidentally query the whole table without a ?limit parameter, and it severely lags the server. I also plan on making this public, and I do not want other users to do this as well. Is there any way to limit the maximum number of rows Postgrest returns? I know its possible because I have seen other Postgrest api's do it.

I'm using Nginx, and the latest Postgrest docker release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `db-max-rows` config:

https://postgrest.org/en/stable/configuration.html#db-max-rows